# What is the appropriate statistical significance test for multi-class classification?

Tags: statistics, multiclass-classification, performance, f1score

I have a multi-class classification problem. I am primarily using macro-average F1 measure to evaluate the performance of models and want to verify if the results are statistically significant. I have the results of two classifiers on the same train/test-set (paired observations).

Some sources suggest to use McNemar’s test for binary classification task. However, is there any generalization of McNemar’s test for multi-class classification problem? If so, what would be the appropriate procedure to carry out these tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalisation of Mcnemars is called [Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Mantel%E2%80%93Haenszel_statistics).

There is an implementation in R, but I suppose porting to Python should not be too hard. You can find the R version [here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat504/node/113/).

Comment: Hello in which section to find the code in R?  Thanks